# Connection refused, port 2222, mac to ubuntu (remote)

Tags: networking, server, ssh, openssh

I can't login from my mac to my ubuntu machine. I tried many things, but nothing works. I am using ubuntu 20.04

Here is what I tried:

- installed openssh-client openssh-server
- changed port from 22 to 2222
- started server -> lissening to port 2222
- added port 22 and 2222 to ufw
- installed and reinstalled openssh-client openssh-server

I can log in from my ubuntu to my ubuntu via
`ssh localhost -p2222`

I can ***not*** login from my ubuntu to my ubuntu via
`ssh name@publicip -p 2222`

I can ***not*** login from my mac to my ubuntu via
`ssh name@publicip -p 2222`

What am I missing?

Comment: Weclome, try your local ip ( 192.168.*.**)

Comment: Hi, I can log into my local ip in my ubuntu machine and now?

Comment: I use the private ipv4 for my ssh, 192.168.1.** that is it.

Comment: Is the "publicip" address you mention the external IP address of your router? Ie. the setup is like this: Internet -> router (external IP=publicip) -> router (internal IP) -> ubuntu (internal IP)? If yes, you won't be able to login to internal IP using external IP because that's just how NAT router works. You have to use the internal IP of your ubuntu if you are connecting within your internal network. If you want to be able to login from the Internet, you need to forward a port on the router.

Comment: @raj Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction :) 

In the end I noticed that my router can't handle ipv4 and that I had to use ipv6...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@raj pointed me in the right direction. My router doesn't have an ipv4 address, just ipv6. Therefor port forwarding is not possible. In the end I had to use the ipv6 address.

Comment: It's strange... I never heard of routers that don't support IPv4. There are routers that don't support IPv6, but I never saw one that doesn't support IPv4. Maybe it doesn't have an IPv4 address assigned, but certainly it does support IPv4... Anyway, if you are able to achive what you want using IPv6, it's fine :)

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right, he doesn't have a IPv4 address. Edited my message.